# Username and password for Remote into SF nodes via RDP

Tags: azure-service-fabric

What username and password should we use to access SF nodes ? 
Is it the same Azure portal username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provided the password as part of the creation of the cluster. For example, it's passed as an [ARM template parameter](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/service-fabric-secure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype/azuredeploy.parameters.json). Fortunately, you can reset the password of your [VM scaleset](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/how-to-reset-password-for-vmss-scale-set-instances/).

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId 'SUBSCRIPTIONID' | Select-AzureRmSubscription

$vmssName = 'SCALESETNAME'
$vmssResourceGroup = 'SCALESETRESOURCEGROUP'
$publicConfig = @{'UserName' = 'USERNAME'}
$privateConfig = @{'Password' = 'NEWPASSWORD'}
$extName = 'VMAccessAgent'
$publisher = 'Microsoft.Compute'
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $vmssResourceGroup -VMScaleSetName $vmssName
$vmss = Add-AzureRmVmssExtension -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss -Name $extName -Publisher $publisher -Setting $publicConfig -ProtectedSetting $privateConfig -Type $extName -TypeHandlerVersion '2.0' -AutoUpgradeMinorVersion $true

Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $vmssResourceGroup -Name $vmssName -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```